# Missing Sharepoint Definition

Tags: upgrade

I am having trouble deleting a rogue site definition found after running stsadm preupdatecheck.

I have run stsadm -o enumallwebs and have found where the template is used.  The trouble is that URL doesn't appear to be on the site.

Url="/sick" LanguageId="1033" TemplateName="Unknown" TemplateId="75811" />

How can I find it basically?!

Thanks.

Lisa

Answer (score 1):

You might try to repair the site with

> stsadm -o databaserepair -url http:// -databasename

Answer (score 0):

So site still exists in the content database but you can browse it - try using SharePoint Designer since it looks directly in the content database.